# Class 'Illuminate\Foundation\Application' not found Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, homestead

I installed via composer the Guzzle and i received this error,

```
> @php artisan package:discover
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Illuminate\Foundation\Application' not found in /home/vagrant/PROJ/memo/laravel_project/bootstrap/app.php:14
Stack trace:
#0 /home/vagrant/PROJ/memo/laravel_project/artisan(20): require_once()
#1 {main}
  thrown in /home/vagrant/PROJ/memo/laravel_project/bootstrap/app.php on line 14

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Illuminate\Foundation\Application' not found in /home/vagrant/PROJ/memo/laravel_project/bootstrap/app.php:14
Stack trace:
#0 /home/vagrant/PROJ/memo/laravel_project/artisan(20): require_once()
#1 {main}
  thrown in /home/vagrant/PROJ/memo/laravel_project/bootstrap/app.php on line 14
Script @php artisan package:discover handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 255
```

this was working before, and now i checked the DIR path and it's all ok.
I also tried composer dump-autoload, composer update, removing composer.lock and vendor, composer install

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Delete vendor folder and composer.lock.

After that

**composer install**

then

**composer update --no-scripts**

Try this, this will solve your error. 
**Note:** Please make sure you have all packages in composer.json.

Comment: Which laravel version you are using?

Comment: i solved the problem now by removing the guzzle from composer.json

Answer (score 3):

Running **composer require laravel/framework** solved the problem in my own case. Answering in case someone googles the same problem and this page comes up