# I have an error in running the "php artisan serve" command in laravel , it gives the following error

Tags: php, laravel, frameworks, laravel-artisan, serve

```
 php artisan serve
```

> PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Illuminate\Foundation\Application' not found in F:\xampp\htdocs\grproject\bootstrap\app.php on line 14
>
> Fatal error: Class 'Illuminate\Foundation\Application' not found in F:\xampp\htdocs\grproject\bootstrap\app.php on line 14

I ran the following command also, but no result, i get the above error again.

```
composer update
```

Comment: Does it also happen if you only type "php artisan" ?

Comment: Is this a fresh installation of Laravel? If so, try deleting the folder and installing again.

Comment: I tried deleting the folder and reinstalling laravel

Comment: yes it happens when i use "php artisan"

Comment: if this continues to happen after deleting vendors and reinstalling, you either are missing the dependencies in your composer.json file or your composer isn't executing properly.  Does vendors/Illuminate exist?

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
php artisan clear-compiled
composer dump-autoload
```

if not work try this `command`

```
composer update --no-scripts
```

try this `command`

```
composer dump-autoload
composer install --no-scripts
```

after done `command` run

```
composer update
```

or check this question [Class 'Illuminate\Foundation\Application' not found Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48199082/class-illuminate-foundation-application-not-found-laravel)

Answer (score 0):

run this line of code.

`php artisan clear-compiled`

`composer dump-autoload -o`

`composer update --no-scripts`

`php artisan serve --host 0.0.0.0`

Hopefully this resolves your problem