# I am facing this problem "Class 'Illuminate\Foundation\Application' not found".What would be the solution?

Tags: php, laravel-5.7

Suddenly i'm facing

> Class 'Illuminate\Foundation\Application' not found"

in my project. Is there any solution or edit require?

I have already updated my composer using this:

```
composer update --no-scripts
```

Here is my `bootstrap\app.php` code:

```
<?php
$app = new Illuminate\Foundation\Application(
    $_ENV['APP_BASE_PATH'] ?? dirname(__DIR__)
);
$app->singleton(
    Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class,
    App\Http\Kernel::class
);
$app->singleton(
    Illuminate\Contracts\Console\Kernel::class,
    App\Console\Kernel::class
);
$app->singleton(
    Illuminate\Contracts\Debug\ExceptionHandler::class,
    App\Exceptions\Handler::class
);
return $app;
```

Comment: Have you tried a `composer dump-autoload` ?

Comment: You may start by showing us some code.. Where your class is loaded? Your composer.json etc... Your question is too vague to be answered at this state

Comment: Check that Illuminate is in your composer.json file

Comment: @TanvirAhmedChowdhury: add the code in your question by updating it. Thank to code formatting, it would make it easier to read it.

Comment: I just tried composer dump-autoload                it shows me : C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\blog>composer dump-autoload
Generating optimized autoload files> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
> @php artisan package:discover --ansi
Discovered Package: beyondcode/laravel-dump-server
Discovered Package: fideloper/proxy
Discovered Package: laravel/tinker
Discovered Package: nesbot/carbon
Discovered Package: nunomaduro/collision
Package manifest generated successfully.                                          Generated optimized autoload files containing 3525 classes

Comment: Do you load the autoload somewhere? `require_once __DIR__.'/your_path/vendor/autoload.php';`

Comment: Try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29764368/fatal-error-class-illuminate-foundation-application-not-found , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48199082/class-illuminate-foundation-application-not-found-laravel

Comment: My composer.json file is HERE : https://ideone.com/BDku1e  @olibiaz

Comment: yes i load the autoload.php in vendor\autoload.php .   @olibiaz

Comment: Thank you all. I didn't notice that i commented      require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';  In the public\index.php .Now i removed that comment and it is worked out.